# A vector field on the tangent bundle which is not equivalent to any second order ODE

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

A second  order  differential  equation on a  manifold  $M$  is  a  vector  field $X$ on $TM$  which  is not  only  a  section of  the vector  bundle $T(T(M)) \to TM  $ with the  obvious structure,  but  also  is  a  section of  another bundle  structure   $(T(T(M)), TM, D\pi)$   where  $\pi:TM \to  M$ is  the standard  map  and  $D\pi$ is  its  differentiation.

> What  is  an  example  of  a real analytic vector  field $ X$ on $TM$, the  tangent  bundle  of a  manifold  $M$,  such  that its set of singularities is  a discret set  and is topological equivalent  to  NO  second  order vector  field?
>
> In  particular, is  there  a  polynomial  vector  field  $X$  on  $\mathbb{R}^2\approx  T\mathbb{R}$  such  that $X$  has  a  finite  number  of  singular  points(a  generic case)  but  $X$  is  not  topological  equivalent  to  any  vector  field in the following form? $$\begin{cases}  x'=y \\ y'=g(x,y)   \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 9):

I guess you want the topological equivalence to preserve the bundle structure of $TM \longrightarrow M$ otherwise it becomes a bit arbitrary, right?

In this case a non-zero vertical vector field will not move the base points at all but still moves around in the fibers. If you have a second order differential equation then you necessarily move the points of the base or it is identically zero. Thus a nonzero vertical vector field should do the job: the existence is clear as you can take a vertical lift of a non-zero vector field on $M$.

Comment: Thank  you  for  your  answer. In  my  question  I do  not  care  about  fiber preserving  equivalent. However, your  point is very  interesting.